# can 3 2x6 x8' wooden board support a 900lb load?

Tags: beam, support

I wish to support a 900 lb motor I want to use 3 2x6x8 for a support beam will this be enough?

Comment: Is this three 2" x 6" x 8' joined together supporting the 900 lb say with a chain  hoist?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, assuming they're small-knot boards in good condition. In fact, one would probably hold, but wouldn't be what I'd call safe.

Be sure to securely fasten the boards together using plenty of nails, screws, or some other mechanism to prevent twisting and other movement.